# Ideal generated by polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ideals

> Suppose $a$, $b$ and $c$ are distinct real numbers. Let $f_1 = (x - a)(x - b) $, $f_2 = (x - b)(x - c)$ and $ f_3 = (x - a)(x - c) $. Then $\langle f_1, f_2, f_3\rangle = 1$.

How to approach this problem ? Any hints ?

Comment: These polynomials are very strongly related to [Lagrange Interpolating Polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial).  But that is much beyond what is asked for here.

Comment: Yeah, I was just computing that only. Multiplying $f_1$ with $1/(c-a)(c-b)$ and similarly others and adding them up gives me 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fancier answer: $\mathbb{C}[x]$ is a PID, so $\langle f_1,f_2,f_3\rangle=\langle g\rangle$.  But then any roots of $g$ will also be roots of $f_1$, $f_2$, and $f_3$.  Since $f_1$, $f_2$, and $f_3$ do not have any roots in common, $g$ cannot have any roots (over $\mathbb{C}$).  Hence $g$ is a unit.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: It's fairly easy to show that $1$ is in this ideal with elementary work (there are fancier reasons, but it's not necessary).

If you look at $f_1-f_2$ and $f_1-f_3$, you get two linear polynomials.  By an appropriate constant factor, you can make these have the same leading coefficient.  Then, by subtracting, you get a nonzero constant, which can be scaled to $1$.

Comment: Its giving me the feeling of some kind of Bezouts theorem for polynomials. I don't know if something like this exists or not. I am trying your hint.

Comment: Indeed, [Bézout's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout's_identity#For_principal_ideal_domains) holds for any PID.  If the ring is a [Euclidean domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_domain), then one can use the Euclidean algorithm and substitution to determine the coefficients in the linear combination.